# Git grep for certain commit messages

Tags: regex, git

I am currently parsing my git repo with the following command.

How can I extend this command to filter/regex/exclude the result of the command below, based on the format of the commit message?

I.e. I would like the command below to only display commit messages that begin in the following format:

```
TICKET-123
```

Any set of characters can then following the ticket number.

```
git log --pretty=format:'{"msg":"%s%b","auth":"%cn"}' $@ tagA..HEAD --no-merges
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `--grep` option to `git log`?

Comment: I am aware of it. Having issues with creating a matching regex for the string above. Are the regexs perl based regex?

Comment: `--grep` defaults to whatever Git was built with, but the `-P` aka `--perl-regexp` option tells Git to use Perl style regular expressions, provided it was built with those as well.

Comment: It looks to me like you're simply trying to match `TICKET-` followed by a number, e.g.`TICKET-[0-9][0-9]*`, which shouldn't require any special grep features.

Comment: I'm almost there with 

`git log -G '[^A-Z0-9\-].*' --pretty=format:'{"msg":"%s%b","auth":"%cn"}' $@ tagA..HEAD --no-merges`

But I'm still capturing more than I want to.

Comment: Need to make the regex generic for:

TICKET-123 : fix a typo

basically after `TICKET-123` we may have any characters. Just as long as the comments starts with the format of `TICKET-123`

Comment: Can you provide some text examples of both desired and not desired matches?